# Role can't see CKeditor options on Body field

Tags: 8

Probably a simple setting somewhere, but I can't find it.

On a Drupal 8 site, I have an editor role, to edit/create blog posts. They can see the body field, but it shows as raw html. The wysiwyg CKEditor doesn't appear for them.

The editor role is assigned to the same CKeditor configuration profile as the Administrator. They have ability to to edit the field and the content type. It's just specifically the CKEditor editing that is unavailable to them.

When I look under role permissions, the only option I see relating to any wysiwyg is "Administer Imce File Manager" and toggling this on/off doesn't make a difference.

I've double-checked that the role can edit simple html all the way up to full advanced html.

thoughts?

Comment: Maybe text formats? Maybe the role isn't allowed to use this text format?

Comment: Yeah, I double checked that and they are set to edit all text formats. I will say I put IMCE editor, but realized it's CKEditor that they should be using - Other than that, still can't find solution

Answer (score 1):

After some trial-and-error, changing role permissions, I was able to narrow things down.

I have a module called Simplify installed. When the permission "View hidden fields" is UN-checked, the role cannot see CKEditor. When I check that, everything works as intended.

Comment: Maybe worth a bug report to Simplify on drupal.org.